# How to link two sliders? When slider1 value goes up slider2 value must come down. But how?

Tags: ios, xcode, uislider

I have two UISliders that both have value range of 1 to 8. 
When app starts slider1 is at value 1 and slider2 is at value 8. When slider1 is moved to value 2, I want slider2 to move to value 7 automatically. So when one slider value goes up, the other slider value comes down.

How do I link these sliders together?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Yes, what have you tried. But I believe what you need to do is override the UISlider delegate method and change the value of slider2 in relation to slider1. I don't believe this could be difficult. I think you just need to look a little harder.

Comment: I solved the problem. Take a look.

Comment: Thanks Ace. I pasted my code example below your answer. It now works thanks to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. I created my own little app and easily implemented the ability. Here's how. What you need to do is connect an action to each of your sliders. That action will get called each time the value changes. Inside each action. Do something like this. In .m

```
@synthesize slider1;
@synthesize slider2;

...

- (IBAction)slider2DidChange:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Value did change");
    int value = [slider2 value];
    NSLog(@"%d", value);
    int newValue = 8 - value;
    [slider1 setValue:newValue animated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)slider1DidChange:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Value did change");
    int value = [slider1 value];
    NSLog(@"%d", value);
    int newValue = 8 - value;
    [slider2 setValue:newValue animated:YES];
}
```

Of course, that also requires that you have four connections.

```
@property (assign) IBOutlet UISlider *slider1; //Connect to slider1
@property (assign) IBOutlet UISlider *slider2; //Connect to slider2


- (IBAction)slider2DidChange:(id)sender; //Connect action to slider2
- (IBAction)slider1DidChange:(id)sender; //Connect action to slider1
```

That's it. I am going to post my little app to Infinite Open Syntax and will supply the link shortly. That way you can download the source and took a look yourself. Cheers!

Comment: Here's the link to the download page. https://sites.google.com/site/infiniteopensyntax/linked-sliders

Comment: You are an Ace and a Legend :) Thank you so much.

Comment: @user1882479, That's my name, don't ware it out. ;). No, really. I'm glad to help.

Comment: Let see if this works... having issues posting code :) Anyways, here's the version that works thanks to you!

`-(IBAction)slider1Changed:(id)sender {
 slider1 = (UISlider *)sender; 
 slider1Value = (float)(slider1.value); 
 slider2 setValue:9-slider1Value; 
}

 -(IBAction)slider2Changed:(id)sender {
 slider2 = (UISlider *)sender; 
 slider2Value = (float)(slider2.value); 
 sliderA setValue:9-slider2Value; 
}`